# How to stop auto music playing on Bluetooth connect

Tags: iphone, music, bluetooth

My mom got an iPhone 6s, and she LOVES it. There is one problem. When she connects to her car Bluetooth (the car is a 2012 Toyota Sienna LE), it automatically plays music, even without opening the music app. She tried Siri, opening and closing the music app, and turning off Bluetooth entirely. None of these work. So, is there a setting or a trick to stop music from playing automatically after she connects to Bluetooth?

Comment: Pause it on the car player. Mine remembers from one session to the next, but it would depend on the individual player I presume. Alternatively, connect it by wire, then the bluetooth won't pick up if it's not hard-wired [same proviso as above, I guess]

Comment: No, it still plays anyways...

Comment: If you want to completely turn off Bluetooth, you should turn it off from the Settings app, not from the control center. Because if you turn it off from the control center, iphone will turn it back on at 5 am next morning. That will probably solve your problem, but in that case, she can't use hands free phone calling while driving. You probably won't want that? In that case, changing the source to Radio, CD or Aux instead of Bluetooth can also solve the problem if you don't want to turn off bluetooth permanently.

Comment: I have this problem and it totally pisses me off. The idea that the iPhone would just randomly start playing music even WHEN THERE ARE ZERO APPS RUNNING violates metaphors like a rusty razor in a punchbowl.

Answer (score 1):

I created a song called "AAA Silence" that fixes this problem at least for iPhones (by being 79 minutes of silence that should always be the first song alphabetically on your phone), and I put it on the iTunes Store and on CD Baby. You can just search for "AAA Silence" in the iTunes Store or on CD Baby to get it. Alternately, you can get direct links to buy it and read more about it at http://aaasilence.com/

Answer (score 0):

Turning the bluetooth connector off, then it stops. 
But if you want the BT connection on, you can try another source on your car media system: select Radio or SD card or DvD or another medium will play that instead of the iPhone music. And it will remember that setting probably (in my car it does).
Normally the iPhone music is played by direct connect via BT to the music library without he music app.

Comment: If we switch audio inputs, it plays through the iPhone speaker.